# Excel VBA keeps adding a dot to the end of my filenames?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an odd problem...

The following code is meant to ask for a filename then save as a standard file (e.g. without macros/vba code) and it works as expected. However; it keeps adding a dot to the end of the filename e.g. when you choose an existing excel filename )say, report for today.xlsx) then amend it to add a new date (say, report for yesterday) and click save the new filename becomes 'report for yesterday..xlsx'

```
    ' open save as.. dialog box
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
    If fName = False Then
    ElseIf fName = "" Then
        fName = "defaultname" 
    Else
        fName = fName & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
```

I **think** it's something to do with the fact that I am selecting an existing name first and it already has an extension but that extension does not appear in the file dialog.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alan

**EDIT:** amended default name to avoid confusion

Comment: `Now` is going to include characters not allowed in filenames, so you should probably format the date somehow first - something like - `Format$(Now, "yyyymmdd")`

Comment: @braX good point - in truth; that bit is never called as I'm the only person using this workbook and I always name the file but I will edit the question so as not to confuse the issue

Comment: Worked OK for me - I opened a .xlsx file and it saved it as .xlsx.xlsx which seems entirely consistent with the code (ie the file extension comes into fname on my PC)

Comment: I don't think you need to add the ".xlsx" if you're not splitting out the filename from filename.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from both [Tin Bum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1302114/tin-bum) & [Nathan_Sav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414798/nathan-sav) - I was incorrectly pulling in the file extension into the `fname` variable then appending the file extension a second time.

I amended `fName = fName & ".xlsx"` to `fName = fName` and now it works fine.

During creating/coding I was only creating a **new** file with a brand new filename (as opposed to selecting an existing file and amending the name) so the problem didn't materialise until the report went live. D'oh!

Hopefully this will help someone else,

Alan